# How can I ask for something from frontend in controller using SignalR and ASP.NET Core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc, signalr

In my manage cars controller I have an action method

```
ParkCar(licenseplate, latitude, longitude)
```

that is called after I press a button on frontend. When I press that button, an ajax request is sent with my current location and the selected car that I want to park.

When the action starts running I want to check some info about the location (ex: if there are to many cars nearby) that was sent and send and display a form on frontend with the message :

> Are you sure you want to park here?

After the question was answered on frontend I want to catch that answer in my controller's action and resume it and park the car if the user wants to or to send a failed attempt if the users doesn't.

I want to obtain something like this:

```
public IActionResult ParkCar(string licenseplate,double lat,double lng)
{
    var car = _carsService.GetCarByLicensePlate(licenseplate);

    // Check how many cars are nearby (1km)
    // If there are too many cars... Send a message to frotend: "Are you sure you want to park here?
    // get the message from frontend

    // if the message sent by user is YES
    _carsService.ParkCar(car, lat, lng);
    _carsService.FindAndAssignCityToCar(car);

    return Ok("Car parked successfully!");

    // else return failed 
}
```

Edit: I forgot to mention that I want this strictly with SignalR.

Comment: It's an academic requirement?

Comment: No, I just want to do this with SignalR... I can easily do this with ajax...but I am new to SignalR and I want to understand more of it and what it can do

Comment: It's an odd  flow you've decided.. i'd Ajax all of it, and put the signal R to use elsewhere..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you'd like to implement real-time client-to-server and server-to-client communications with SignalR in your application, you can refer to this doc to create a hub and hub methods based on your actual requirement and scenario.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-5.0#create-and-use-hubs

then you can implement SignalR JavaScript client code in your corresponding view page(s), and connect to your hub server and invoke the hub method(s) in your code logic.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/javascript-client?view=aspnetcore-5.0

> How can I ask for something from frontend in controller using SignalR and ASP.NET Core MVC

Based on the code of your `ParkCar` action method, we can find that your call `_carsService` methods to do business logic, so you can inject same service in your hub method and perform same code logic in your hub method(s).